# businessstore.microsoft.com oauth authentication

Tags: powershell, oauth

I wanted to create a Microsoft flow (linked to a PowerApps) or even a PS script connected to the business store ...

I found that when browsing to businessstore.microsoft.com, under "devices", a call is made to an API to get the required information (the list of devices on my tenant in this case).

When I do a Fiddler trace, I can retrieve some useful information. And if I take the bearer token, I can directly make some calls against the API to get what I want. My problem is to get the right bearer token... I have found no way for the moment.

So I hoped someone could help me to find a way to authenticate, get this bearer token without having to use a web browser and fiddler... by using ADAL for exemple or other ways...

here the information I have:

```
$MicrosoftStoreURL = "https://businessstore.microsoft.com/en-us/manage/devices/all"

$clientid = "45a330b1-b1ec-4cc1-9161-9f03992aa49f"
$redirectURI = "https://businessstore.microsoft.com/auth/"
$APIHost = "businessstoremgmtapiprod.azure-api.net"
$DevicesURI = "https://businessstoremgmtapiprod.azure-api.net/BD-PROD/devicemgmt/devices?api-version=1.0"
```

so with that, I can connect to the business store, get to bearer token with Fiddler (and the x-APIM-key but it's always the same) and get the devices :

```
$uri = "https://businessstoremgmtapiprod.azure-api.net/bd-prod/devicemgmt/devices?api-version=1.0"
$headers = @{
"Authorization" = ("Bearer <TOKEN_ID>")
"x-APIM-Key" = "08149b32571f450ca031f315a1d3e64e"
}
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get).Results
```

I have also tried  to get access by using my own native application which is registered on my tenant but I can't find the right permission.

So again, how to get this token by using a Oauth2 authentication in the PowerApps connector or by using PowerShell and ADAL